# Error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: invalid map key: map[interface {}]interface {}{"if .Values.configmap.enabled":interface {}(nil)} [kubeval] linter

Tags: yaml

`{{- if .Values.configmap.enabled }}

apiVersion: v1

kind: ConfigMap

metadata:

name: {{ template "fullname" . }}

namespace: {{ .Values.namespace }}

data:

{{ toYaml $.Values.configmap.data | indent 2 }}

{{- end }}`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

make sure that there must be space after/before curly brackets
namespace: {{ .Values.namespace }}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).